# What is the best way to manage models when interoperating Rust with other languages?

Tags: c#, typescript, rust, interop

## Background

I am currently working on a library that is entirely written in Rust but that will be consumed by programming languages other than Rust. While talking across the FFI boundary has been simple, writing models in other programming languages that map 1:1 to the Rust models have not been. This question revolves around whether tooling or best practices exist to ease the idea of model generation across the FFI boundary

## Current Approach

My current approach when it comes to this is as follows:

- All of the models that are required for the cross-FFI-boundary communication are Serde serializable.
- All of the `extern` functions accept a pointer to a string and return a pointer to a string.
- Function invocations take a string of the JSON serialized arguments and returns a string of the JSON serialized response. Meaning that the client language needs to have a set of models which serialize in an identical way to those written in Rust.

## Problem

As mentioned in the background, while the communication across the FFI boundary has been quite simple, writing models which map (and serialize) exactly to the ones written in Rust has not been. Currently, my Rust library has 5 wrappers written in 5 different programming languages and the process of writing, testing, and iterating over those DTO models has been far from simple.

## Questions

- Does there exist a method of describing the models and the functions exported from my library in a sane way which could be then used by some tool to generate models or at least a minimal wrapper?
- Is sending JSON across the FFI boundary an issue in any way?
- Are there any best-practices here which I'm oblivious to? or solutions to these problems?

## Alternative Methods Tried

- **Protocol Buffers:** I have experimented with using protocol buffers instead of JSON and hand-written models. However, protocol buffers suffer from two main problems which made them unideal for my use case:

  - Protocol buffers do not have some of the primitive types that I need. As an example: 8-bit integers, 16-bit integers, and 128-bit integer types. Where I would like to enforce that certain types are limited to 8-bits and that models generated of these types should use the 8-bit integer type available in the other language.
  - Protocol buffers assume that all fields are optional and they can't be made otherwise. While this is fine for most applications, the library that I'm building would much rather panic at runtime than deal with defaults of optional fields.
- **Cap'n'proto:** This has mostly similar issues to the above, where it forces that all fields should be made optional which is a no-go for my use case.
- **OpenAPI:** I have tried for a brief period of time describing all of the models using an OpenAPI schema which client languages could then use to generate models. This had the following issues:

  - Models generated through OpenAPI code generators are often times unreadable, don't compile, and hard to understand or iterate over.

Comment: Why not use some stable ABI, like `#[repr(C)]`?

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to have an opaque model, handing the client a pointer or handle to the actual object, and write in the library a bunch of accessor function to inspect its contents. That way the client code does not need to map anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using plain old [`jsonschema`](https://json-schema.org/) for this purpose? While OpenAPI is more targeted to web apis specifically, you could write that schema for your models and use models generated from the schema for both your library and the clients.

Edit: The only major issue that I can see with the "sending json strings through the FFI boundaries" is that you will be necessarily adding the overhead of serialization/deserialization, which might not be trivial.

Comment: On second reading, not sure if that's what you meant by using OpenAPI or not. Apologies if that is more or less what you tried.

Personal experience has been that the jsonschema models tend to be fairly simple, but that might have just been because I was working with simple models to begin with